# Splitting JavaScript code in several files: best practices

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im working only 2 weeks with ExtJS. And all my code looks like one big file. I have many included panels and other ExtJS objects in code. Looks like a big tree )
Can any give some simple advices for defining, storing code parts of JS files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things that fit into their own file fall into two broad categories:

**Models**

Any object constructor function. Any set of functions that handle data. Any business logic. Validation logic.

Anything that handles logically manipulating data on a page without writing / reading from the DOM.

**Views**

Anything that renders to the page. Template files. anything that manipulates DOM objects.

There are also miscellaneous things that fit into their own files

- Server-Client communication, Websockets, ajax.
- Micro frameworks
- Utility belts
- Routing helpers.

There are some things which are difficult to insolate into their owns files like the event based messaging that links your views to your models.

Generally you want to either use a packing tool to mix all your small files into one large file to send to the server or use a module loader like [require](http://requirejs.org/).

Anything that you think can be modularized can be placed into its own file.

Comment: There is not much more to say. For performance reasons you should minify the calls to the server but that also covered above.

Comment: I am mobile at the moment but I use two at the moment. I will answer you this as soon as I am back to my notebook...

Comment: At the moment I am using the YUI Compressor for .Net http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/. But I planned to take a closer look an the Google Closure compiler. I create up to 75% of my JavaScript on the fly, so I chooses this

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself repeating code you can make those classes, and those can go into their own file. In addition you can split along panel lines regardless of whether they're repeated or not.

So for an application teaching users how to turn their minimally trained grizzly bears into lifetime companions, you might end up with files like this:

- BearsAreNotDeadly.js
- Search.js
- Tutorials.js
- GruesomePictures.js
- ComplaintForm.js

... with each of those being a part of the application.